# Manage and access list SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to access a value from a list in SharePoint to display it in a text field. Is there a way to do this with no code, using only the tools provided by the web application?

I tried adding the list access by url in the text field but it didn't work.

My try was something like this

```bash
# I'm using the spanish version of the app so the function names are in Spanish
=CONCATENAR("sharepoint_url/lists/Products")
```

The result was the literal text `=CONCATENAR(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean. If you want to display the value of another list in one list, you can try using lookup column.
If this doesn't meet your needs, you can try customizing with Power Apps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint/scenarios-sharepoint-form-from-scratch#step-5--add-the-capability-to-search-and-select-item